# Removing single 1212 (3030) LED

Tags: led, soldering, surface-mount, replacement

Is there any way to remove and replace a single 1212 (3030) LED from a heat-sink board as shown in the images?

[image: Front]

[image: Back]

Comment: Looks like a thin grey sheet covering up the copper tracks underneath, your first challenge is to get that off without damaging anything.

Comment: Sounds highly unlikely

Comment: If the LED is dead then directed hot air can probably be used to remove it. This will then give you a better chance of assessing how to mount the replacement. If visible solder points exist you MAY be able to extend a short "wing" out from each point and then sit the new LED on the extensions are edge solder. Will not look pretty but may be functional.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Thank you. It's worth a shot as the whole board is dead anyway.

Comment: @Jak For interest - if dead why do you want to replace the LED? What is it? - looks interesting. Appears to have a number of different LEDs.

Comment: looks like some sort of commercial led floodlight.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon It's an LED grow light, hence the different colour LEDs. It seems like a waste to have a dead board sitting around doing nothing. Reduce, reuse...

Comment: @JAk Indeed. If the above suggestion doesn't work and you do not mind a terrible cosmetic effect you could mount a LED in about the right place and run wiring to it from somewhere suitable. Looks terrible. Works as was as far as lighting is concerned. Small piece of PCB with Al on other side and thermal transfer compound and ... .

Answer (score 0):

Tin and flux the replacement

Heat the board until the solder melts.  (perhaps use a large gas flame at the back)

With the solder molten lift off the bad part. place the

replacement allow to cool.